# image not respecting the class i gave it

Tags: html, css, image

The image below is not respecting the CSS class I have given it.

[image: Screenshot]

I gave it a max height and width and it's not respecting that and as you can see there just expanding accross the page.

**CSS**

```
.tagline-img
{
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 330px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://deadcyborg.com/deadcyborg_ep2wip1.jpg" class="tagline-img" alt="[articleimage]" />
```

The page is viewable at: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/test/

Comment: There's no matching definition in your `style.css` file for `.tagline-img`...

Comment: There is, it's in my post and in the style.css as i copied the css from the file.

Comment: Which file is it located in? Do a search in this file for your definition > http://www.gamingonlinux.com/templates/default/style.css

Comment: Your .tagline-img css class is not defined, as I've inspected with firebug

Comment: Crap sorry it's linking to the wrong css file!

Comment: It's best practice to insert an image or fiddle instead of providing a link to the faulty page in case it doesn't exist in the future.  I've inserted a screenshot.

Comment: So, was this solved? If so, please post answer and mark as correct. I'm having a similar issue. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include your CSS definition inside of [`style.css`](http://www.gamingonlinux.com/templates/default/style.css).

Doing a search for your `.tagline-img` doesn't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.articles-content img
    {
        max-width: 350px;
        max-height: 330px;
    }
```

Comment: Well no because it's not in a parent element called "tagline"

Comment: @LiamDawe i was confused. edited the answer, try that. also i tried adding inline style in your page and it worked

Comment: This isn't the issue. The issue is that the style provided in the question isn't actually present in any of the stylesheets included on that page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `tagline-img` styling in any of the CSS files included on that page. Are you sure you actually uploaded the modified stylesheet?

Answer (score -1):

You are not applying any class style to the image on the link you gave us: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/test/

Check your stylesheet is being loaded correctly.

You can check it using Chrome inspector:

[image]